# Permission denied forbidding nginx centos

Tags: nginx, centos

I am facing an error of permission I am working on ruby on rails deployments on nginx. But I am not sure what is the glitch.

> [error] 10886#0: *6
>   "/home/deploy/projects/project_name/public/index.html" is forbidden
>   (13: Permission denied)

Here is my vhost

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name    blog.test.com;
    #return 301    http://blog.test.com$request_uri;

    #root /home/deploy/projects/project_name/public;



    location / {
        root /home/deploy/projects/project_name/public;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index  index.html  index.htm;   
        autoindex on;
        allow   127.0.0.1;
    }

}
```

Comment: does nginx have correct permissions to access the directory? Is selinux enabled, if so you will need to set `setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs true`

Comment: I have the name of nginx my user and assign chmod -R 0777 to public and chown -R nginx:nginx but it is not working for me

Comment: run `getenforce` to see if selinux is running